# Return number of Business days since deadline as integer and add Business days to date with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want a function to return the number of Business days since a specific date and to add Business Days to a date, accounting for NAs
However, my solution is sloppy and there should be a more elegant way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(timeDate)
library(RQuantLib)
library(lubridate)


item <- c("a", "b")
date1 = as.Date(c("2017-11-30", "2017-11-01"))
date2 = as.Date(c("2017-12-01", "2017-11-16"))
d <- data.frame(item, date1, date2, stringsAsFactors=F)

line3 <- c("c", "2017-12-03", NA)
line4 <- c("d", NA, "2017-12-03")
d <- rbind(d, line3, line4)
```

This function works, but runs very slow accross multiple items, also not very legible.

```
bizDeadline <- function(x, nBizDys = 10) {
  output <- Reduce(rbind, Map((function(x, howMuch = 15) {
    x <- as.Date(x, origin = "1960-01-01")
    days <- x + 1:(howMuch * 2)
    Deadline <- days[isBizday(as.timeDate(days))][howMuch]
    data.frame(DateIn = x, Deadline, DayOfWeek = weekdays(Deadline), TimeDiff = difftime(Deadline,
                                                                                         x))
  }), x, howMuch = nBizDys))
  output$Deadline
}
```

This would be ideal to exclude holidays and weekends.

```
d %>% mutate(deadline = bizDeadline(date1, 10))

d$DaysOverdue <- NA
```

This works with a loop: but doesn't work in vectorized Mutate.

```
i = 1
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
  d$DaysOverdue[i] = businessDaysBetween("UnitedStates", d$date1[i], today())
}
```

This function from RQuantLib seems not to be vectorized

```
d %>% mutate(od = businessDaysBetween("UnitedStates", date1, today())
```

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I recommend you to use `Vectorize` function in R. This is easy well to vectorize some function. P.s. This function can't to deal with NA

```
businessDaysBetween_vec <- Vectorize(businessDaysBetween,vectorize.args = c('from', 'to'))

d[1:2,] %>% mutate(od = businessDaysBetween_vec("UnitedStates", date1, today()))


#Checking and comparing speed of solution
foo_loop <- function() {
  for(i in 1:2){
    d$DaysOverdue[i] = businessDaysBetween("UnitedStates", d$date1[i], today())
  } 
}
require(microbenchmark)
require(ggplot2)
res <- microbenchmark(businessDaysBetween_vec(),foo_loop(),times = 1e5)
autoplot(res)
```

[image: result]